# Best way to store XML data in a MySQL database, with some specific requirements

Tags: mysql, xml, database, data-structures

I am receiving XML data from a service. The test data I am receiving back has about 300 XML nodes, clearly far too many to create individual rows for in a MySQL database.

The problem is that we ideally need to store *all* the data, and we will probably need to reference the data again at some point in the future - we can't just process through it once and delete the XML string.

What's the best way of storing this data in a MySQL database?

I have forecast that at the predicted rate within a few months, if we were to store the raw XML data in `TEXT` format, the database could grow to around 500MB. In the long run this feels impractical.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could create a `blob` column (i.e. `mediumtext` column). Instead of inserting XML purely as strings in the DB, you could zip the XML, then store in MySQL.

When you read from MySQL, you unzip it again. Since XML is text you'll get very high compression rates (close to 80% compression). The thought process being, disk IO takes a lot longer time than compression/un-compression which is predominantly Processor bound.

The downside being you will no longer be able to query or do full text search using SQL....

Comment: Thanks @Srikar, I find this solution exactly matching to my requirement. I only need to store xml document in DB for future reference, no queries will be made on stored XML document. My only concern was over the time, the storage requirement to store xml files may increased dramatically. For that, I will compress files before storing in DB.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to not store XML in the DB, but I have history with that particular issue.

Just store it as TEXT.  500 MB is nothing for MySql, especially with TEXT datatypes, since those aren't stored in the row buffer.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [LOAD XML](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html) command. This statement is available in MySQL 5.5.

Answer (score 3):

A lot depends on what you want to do with the data - if you want to search for stuff within the XML, then [decomposing it into a tree](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/) will give much better query performance.

500Mb is not a huge amount of data - the issues are all about how you reference it and search it. If it's just for archiving purposes or you never need to search inside the XML, then compressing it then (e.g.) base64 encoding will reduce this down to less than 80Mb