# best way store large text in a table, XML or JSON?

Tags: mysql, xml, json, database

I have a form with 4 fields which each one will be filled with a lot of text +/- 300 words.
this form will be filled once in a week for every user of the system, the system have like 1300 users and growing. Actually im using a mySQL database. The question is, what would be the best solution to store this data?

- storing in a table in mySQL with 'TEXT' data type columns for then do a 'select * from mytable where id=myuserID'
- store it in a JSON or XML file for each user and save it in the server?

What would be better

Comment: Then I would just store that data inside TEXT column; no need to make your backup strategy more complicated by introducing separate files.

Comment: even when the table will have a lot of rows?, and when I retrieve all the rows for a specific user, the query will not last long time?

Comment: The speed of retrieval depends less on the columns requested than the presence of index keys.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009538/best-way-to-store-xml-data-in-a-mysql-database-with-some-specific-requirements).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to save this data on your server as a xml-file and only save the path in the mySQL database.

This is how I do it.

Answer (score 0):

for large text, I usually save in a plain text file (for example: chat history, map coordinate) and the table just for storing the path of the file.